# Error on genymotion power_supply

Tags: android, cordova, logcat, genymotion

Im using genymotion to emulate my cordova app, and the logcat shows me this error every time.

E/Genymotion(  459): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'

To run my app I'm using a shell command:

```
cordova build && adb install -r platforms\android\bin\Example-debug.apk && adb shell am start -n br.com.example/br.com.example.Example
```

And to see the logcat I'm using:

```
adb logcat
```

Comment: What is the exact problem concerning your app?

Comment: Actually my app works fine, but this error keeps jumping in the log every 10 sec.

Comment: Ok. That's not a real problem though. It is not concerning your app directly. I post you a way to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android tools allows you to filter the log output.
Your can use [DDMS](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) to show the logs and add a filter corresponding to your app.

Fill the filter field with your package name for example and you will only see the logs generated by your app.
You won't be annoyed more by these logs.

Comment: Thanks, this works fine for me, what I did,was silence every log from genymotion by the commad `adb logcat Genymotion:S`  here is a  link [Reading and Writing Logs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-log.html) for those who need to set up logcat at console.