# Error on genymotion power_supply.. T_T

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I need to run the game application
But does not run
What should I do?
▼ genymotion logcat

```
E/Genymotion(  323): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
```

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18728099/error-on-genymotion-power-supply

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE:

Try [Genymotion | Installing ARM Translation and GApps](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952),which explains why we meet this error and how can we fix it in detail.

Simply Steps:

1: Try to fetch the file named `Genymotion-ARM-Translation`
2: Drag the zip file directly into your Genymotion emulator,confirm the popped up window;
3: Restart the emulator.That's it.

Comment: Genymotion is a Virtual Android Environment built on x86 and Virtualbox. It's not an ARM emulator so it's performance is way better than the Android SDK Emulator. However in their latest update they've removed both ARM Translation and Google Play Apps. (This is what causes the "INSTALL_FAILED_CPU_ABI_INCOMPATIBLE" errors).Ps:i get the very explain 4 the problem,refer blow for detail.http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952