# Why don't start genymotion via eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, genymotion

I installed  genymotion and virtual box. I installed the genymotion plugin on the eclipse.When click on the genymotion icon on eclipse toolbar show me all virtual devices that installed in genymotion. Then I double click on the once of virtual device name or I select once and click start but genymotion doesn't start.

```
    10-14 05:40:05.812: E/Genymotion(329): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
10-14 05:40:10.816: E/Genymotion(329): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
10-14 05:40:15.820: E/Genymotion(329): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
10-14 05:40:20.820: E/Genymotion(329): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
10-14 05:40:25.824: E/Genymotion(329): Could not open '/sys/class/power_supply/genymotion_fake_path/present'
```

Comment: You'll need to post some error logs of some kind. Can you launch genymotion manually at least without going through eclipse?

Comment: Yes. I  run genymotion  manually and then click on the play button on the eclipse and then genymotion run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general problem is mistake path of genymotion .I right click on the genymotion icon then get path and put it into window\prefrences\genymotion directory . Now it worked properly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ,see if [Error on genymotion power_supply.. T_T](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20953589/error-on-genymotion-power-supply-t-t/26291376#26291376)  the same problem;

BTW ,if you have truly device, you can use this [Vysor](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vysor-beta/gidgenkbbabolejbgbpnhbimgjbffefm?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog) ,Vysor lets you view and control your Android on your computer. Easy peasy.
More detail [here](http://www.vysor.io/).

Also,Why not try Android Studio,most projects in gitHub now are android studio projects...

Comment: Android studio is very slow in my computer

Comment: Your are welcome , it's good to see you fixed this problem :) @programmer138200